# Jquery Class - Add An Increment To It

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to add a dynamically-generated number at the end of "myclass" in Jquery. So I want it to increment a number at the end like this:

myclass1

myclass2

myclass3

myclass4

I've tried a few times but have no clue what I'm doing. Any help would be great!

```
  var f=1;for(var g=0;g<d.count;g++)for(var f=1; f<3; f++){e.append("<li class='myclass"+f+"'><a>"+f+"</a></li>");f++}
```

Comment: can you show more of your code?  Not sure if that's your html or a js string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but here's my take on it. Of course, you can be more specific on the jQuery selector.

```
var i = 1;
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('myclass'+i);
    i++;
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on the code provided:

```
for(var f = 1; f < 5; f++){
    e.append("<li class='myclass"+f+"'><a>"+f+"</a></li>");
    f++;
}
```

Comment: I edited the code to show a bit more code.  Does your answer change considering this is inside of a bigger function?

Comment: See edit. I still don't know much about your code so I'm only guessing here.

Comment: Yes, that adds the appropriate class, although it added more `<li>` items. Weird. It added another 3 list items. For example `<li class="myclass1">`, `<li class="myclass3">`, and `<li class="myclass1">` in that exact order when I only have 3 slides (since this is for slider.

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, so it's hard for me to help you :P If you tell me what your HTML looks like **before** that JS, and what you want it to look like **after**, then I might be able to help you more.

Comment: Hi mbinette, it seems the HTML is not showing. The list items we are editing are for a slider navigation. The slider HTML is located here http://www.richmindonline.com/ending-poverty/, but I can't find the navigation HTML.  I also expanded my code in the original question.

Comment: mbinette, never mind on my last comment.  Based on your code, I found that the variables were defined a bit earlier in the code, so I removed that part and it worked with the `f++` attached to my class.  Thank you!