# How to add a class to a div dynamically using JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

In my markup I have two div with same class   .  I want to add two different class in each div .

My html code is look like

```
<div class="my-class">
    --Content--
</div>

<div class="my-class">
    --Content--
</div>
```

But I want that two div as

```
<div class="my-class class-1">
    --Content--
</div>

<div class="my-class class-2">
    --Content--
</div>
```

So , if there is with a class **"my-class"** , I want to add an addition class to div like class-(1 to N) , How can I do this ?

Comment: How are you adding your dynamically generated content?

Comment: A bit OT: are you using the `class` attribute for styling or to identify the DIV later on? If for identity purposes I would recommend giving each class an `ID` attribute rather than a class name using one of the techniques displayed in the answers below.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610686/jquery-class-add-an-increment-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var c = 1;
$(".my-class").each(function(){
$(this).addClass("class-" + c);
c++;
});
```

Comment: You can use the iterator of your 'each' function

Comment: one issue that you may find with my solution is that jQuery's .each function is super slow. It is better to use JavaScript for loop. Either way, this is a solution that gets the job done in an easy way to understand.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
$('.my-class').each(function(ind, ele) {
    var id = (ind+1);
    $(ele).addClass('class-' + id);
});
```

[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9L7prjh/)

Comment: @MurtazaHussain ...what do you mean? How would you do it without `each`?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want.

```
var classes = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');
for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
    classes[i].classList.add('class-'+i); 
    //classes[i].className += 'class-'+i; -> older browsers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also use `.each()` function, here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh64c42u/) for example.

```
$(".my-class").each(function(i) {
 $(this).addClass("yourClass"+(i+1));
});
```

This will do the magic.

Hope it helps